# CustomView and CustomButton in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I have created two custom classes : CutomView Class (subclass of UIView) and CustomButton Class(subclass of UIButton).

```
class CustomView: UIView {

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
        layer.masksToBounds = true
        layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        layer.borderColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 0.0/255, green: 64.0/255, blue: 128.0/255, alpha: 1).CGColor
        layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
        let startColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 255.0/255, green: 204.0/255, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
        let endColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 0, green: 128.0/255, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = CGRect(origin: layer.frame.origin, size: layer.frame.size)
        gradientLayer.colors = [startColor, endColor];
        layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    }
```

and

```
@IBDesignable
class CustomButton: UIButton {
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
        layer.masksToBounds = true
        layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        layer.borderColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 0.0/255, green: 64.0/255, blue: 128.0/255, alpha: 1).CGColor
        layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
        let startColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 192.0/255, green: 192.0/255, blue: 192.0/255, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
        let endColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 239.0/255, green: 239.0/255, blue: 239.0/255, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = CGRect(origin: layer.frame.origin, size: layer.frame.size)
        gradientLayer.colors = [startColor, endColor];
        layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    }

}
```

I used those custom subclasses to design the view and buttons. When I view the applied custom class they are working fine but for some reasons the button is not visible in simulator or the iOS Device.

It will be great if somebody could point me to the bug or help me fix it.

[Storyboard and Preview shows the purple blue background and button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aobr8.png)

[Simulator only displays purple blue background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xwxc6.png)

Comment: how u adding button in your code? Update code or try to set title using button.settile method

Comment: @Shobhakar Tiwari I am using storyboard to add the button and set the class as CustomButton for button.

Comment: okey so button is not showing on storyboard , have u set ibdesignable property in storyboard

Comment: What are you using for layout? Autolayout or are you programmatically sizing it?

Comment: @AndrewMcKinley I have centred button vertically and horizontally. Trailing and Leading 20.

Comment: Sounds like you're missing a height. After the view loads try printing out the frame.

Comment: @AndrewMcKinly the button is was created using storyboard so it had it's regular height and width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `layer.addSublayer` call  appends the layer to your hierarchy of layers. Thus, the gradient is the last thing drawn, effectively painting over your custom button.  You want your gradient to be the background, so make sure it's the first layer drawn.  Change

`layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)`

to

`layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, atIndex: 0)`

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks Curmudgeonlybumbly

Comment: @beyowulf Thanks for the help. Your suggestion changing the view.frame to self.view.bounds was part of the solution.